# Advantages of Powershell for web-ui testing?

Tags: testing, powershell

I am working on a commercial project which is a web-based app which will be bundled with an app/web server (JBoss), which is deployed, with the web app files, at runtime.

I've seen links about how Powershell can do UI testing. Is there any advantage in Powershell for web-testing as opposed to Selenium or VS2010's coded UI tests? (Selenium has poor documentation, which is in Powershell's favour, but I am interested in more functional reasons).

Thanks

Comment: The one thing that comes to mind is that powershell is more of a general purpose tool where tools like selenium, watir, etc tend to be more niche.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell will give you advantage if you need to manipulate something else than a browser/webpage/webapp. With Powershell you can do something with OS, applications, things outside the browser.

If you don't need to do that, if you want to automate only web based app, than I would suggest using web specific tool. Selenium is nice, tests in MSVS2010 are great. If you prefer coding try [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) for .net, and [WatiJ](http://watij.com/) for java. All of them will run smoothly not only inside IDE, but also on CI server.